Failing to store WhatsApp Messages sent to Twilio in Google Sheets
I am using Twilio's test account for a proof of concept. I want to store details in the whatsapp message such as sender, message body and status in a Google Sheet. I created the WebApp and added the webhook in "When a message comes in" field in the sandbox configuration and set the method to Post.
Here is my WebApp configuration in Google App Script;
function doPost(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  try {
    // Check if request contains parameters (for x-www-form-urlencoded)
    if (e.parameter && Object.keys(e.parameter).length > 0) {
      // Extract parameters
      const from = e.parameter.From || "Unknown";
      const body = e.parameter.Body || "No message content";
      const status = e.parameter.MessageStatus || "No status";

      // Log extracted parameters
      Logger.log("Parsed parameters - From: " + from + ", Body: " + body + ", Status: " + status);

      // Append data to Google Sheets
      sheet.appendRow([
        new Date(), // Timestamp
        from, // Sender's phone number
        body, // Message content
        status // Message status
      ]);

      // Log success message
      Logger.log("Data successfully appended to Google Sheets.");

      // Return a plain text response
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Message received").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
    } else {
      // If no parameters are found, throw an error
      throw new Error("No x-www-form-urlencoded data detected.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Log error details
    Logger.log("Error: " + error.message);
    Logger.log("Error stack: " + error.stack);

    // Return an error response
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error processing request").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }
}

I keep getting an error this error;
{
  "insertId": "3cd6x3e3e6ls",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "serviceContext": {
      "service": "XXXXXX",
      "version": "1"
    },
    "context": {
      "reportLocation": {
        "functionName": "doPost",
        "lineNumber": 1,
        "filePath": "undefined"
      }
    },
    "message": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'S', \"SmsMessage\"... is not valid JSON\n    at doPost(Code:3:25)"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "app_script_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "doPost",
      "invocation_type": "web app",
      "project_id": "XXXXX"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-12-03T15:17:49.574Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "script.googleapis.com/deployment_id": "XXXX",
    "script.googleapis.com/project_key": "XXXXX",
    "script.googleapis.com/process_id": "XXXX"
  },
  "logName": "projects/xxxxx/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-12-03T15:17:49.715267499Z",
  "errorGroups": [
    {
      "id": "COWYns2l-5-hlQE"
    }
  ]
}

Need help fixing this.
I used postman to test and I got the same error.

About your error message, where is the line 3 of doPost? I'm worried that your deployed script might be different from your showing script. And also, can you provide the sample value of e?

I copied and pasted the script from Google Apps Script. With twilio, I cannot see the raw data directly, connected to Google console as well but nothing.

It seems you are quering the e object wrong. I suggest you to log the entire e object in a sheet as console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 4) and check its strucure.
